# Get And Download File in Django

Tags: python, django

I want users to be able to download a short movie after paying a fee. I've been able to make the payment gateway work.

This is what I want to do: After a user pay, and the payment is successful, he will be redirected back to the previous page where he will download the file.

The challenge I'm facing is to output the download link in the template for the user to download after payment. I wrote the below codes, yet no success, the if statement is not bringing out the download link:

Views.py

## page where it will output download link

```
@csrf_exempt
def item_view(request,urlhash):        
    post = get_object_or_404(Arts,urlhash=urlhash)
    stats= Arts.objects.filter(urlhash=urlhash).update(usage_count=F('usage_count')+1)
    currentUrl=request.build_absolute_uri()
    return render_to_response('postdetail.html',{'Arts':Arts,'post':post, 'stats':stats, 'currentUrl':currentUrl},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

## moviefile view to download

```
@login_required
def document_view(request, arts_id):
    document=Arts.objects.get(id=arts_id)
    response = HttpResponse()
    response["Content-Disposition"]= "attachment; filename={0}".format(document.pretty_name)
    response['X-Accel-Redirect'] = "/protected_files/{0}".format(document.upfile.name)
    return response
```

Template

## paymentpage

```
<form method='POST' action='https://mackpay.com/pay/'>

   {% csrf_token %}

   <input type='hidden' name='v_merchant_id' value='{{newpayy.v_merchant_id}}' />
   <input type='hidden' name='item_1' value='{{ newpayy.art.title }}' />
   <input type='hidden' name='description_1' value='{{ newpayy.art.description }}' />
   <input type='hidden' name='price_1' value='{{ newpayy.art.price }}' />

   <input type='hidden' name='notify_url' value='127.0.0.1:8000/final_result'/>

    #page to redirect to after payment
     <input type='hidden' name='success_url' value='http://127.0.0.1:8000/i/{{ newpayy.art.urlhash }}/' />


   <input type='image' src='http://mackpay.com/images/buttons/buynow_blue.png' alt='Make Payment' />

   </form>
```

## page for download

```
{% if request.META.HTTP_REFERER == 'https://mackpay.com/pay/' %}

  <p> Download: <a href="{% url document_view post.id %}"> Get Stuff</a> </p>

{% endif %}
```

Any idea on how to go about this?

Comment: and what exactly is not working

Comment: It's not bringing out the download link in the template. The if statement now working. {% if request.META.HTTP_REFERER == 'https://mackpay.com/pay/' %}

  <p> Download: <a href="{% url document_view post.id %}"> Get Stuff</a> </p>

{% endif %}

Comment: Are you missing quotes - <a href="{% url 'document_view' post.id %}"> as per the document https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/